# Cannot create custom mount point for /dev in systemd

Tags: boot, upstart, systemd

I am working in an embedded system and we are migrating from upstart to systemd. I am trying to write .mount file for /dev in rootfs. But this failing. Can somebody please help ?

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=/dev Directory
Documentation=man:hier(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/dev
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777
```

My filename is `dev.mount`.

I am getting the following error : `Cannot add dependency job for unit dev.mount, ignoring: Unit dev.mount failed to load: Invalid argument`

I have posted same question in stack overflow. If it is wrong, I am ready to remove that or this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242232/cannot-create-custom-mount-point-for-dev-in-systemd